# I am trying to convert string("08:55 AM") into timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, time

I have to convert a string value into `TimeSpan`. But its showing an error.

> String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.

The code is:

```
TimeSpan _time = TimeSpan.Parse("08:55 AM");
```

I know it can parse the string value in `"08:55"`. But I don't need that. I have to use AM or PM in the string.
In the database, the column datatype is `time(7)` and I am using `entity framework`.

Comment: a `TimeSpan` is the length of time something took;  `"8:55 AM"` isn't a length of time, it's a specific time.  If you have a specific time, use `DateTime` instead.

Comment: What about [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: In the database, the column datatype is time(7) and I am using entity framework. So I have to use the TimeSpan.

Comment: The database certainly doesnt need the AM/PM.  Parse it using DateTime.Parse, then save `dtVar.TimeOfDay` for the db

Comment: It shows the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.TimeSpan?'"
Code is: 
TimeSpan _time = DateTime.Parse("08:55 AM");

Comment: @Claies Then why does `DateTime.TimeOfDay` return a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @Lukazoid I tried to better explain my comment with the answer I posted.

Answer (score 5):

The SQL `Time` datatype does not store the time of day;  instead, it stores the time as the number of milliseconds since midnight.

Converting the AM version of `"08:55"` to a timespan is equivalent to saying "8 hours and 55 minutes since midnight", while the PM version would be `"20:55"`, "20 hours and 55 minutes since midnight".  The `TimeSpan` object doesn't do this calculation intrinsically, but you can simulate the result.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        DateTime timespan = DateTime.Parse("08:55 AM");  //gives us a DateTime object
        DateTime timespan2 = DateTime.Parse("08:55 PM");

        TimeSpan _time = timespan.TimeOfDay;  //returns a TimeSpan from the Time portion
        TimeSpan _time2 = timespan2.TimeOfDay;
        Console.WriteLine(_time);
        Console.WriteLine(_time2);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XVLVPl

Answer (score 3):

Since "08:55 AM" is a specific time not a span, it is failing to parse.  However, it sounds like you may want the time since midnight, or noon depending on whether it is AM or PM

So I see 2 approaches here.  One, is to strip the AM/PM from the time before parsing.  as in:

```
string timeValue = "08:55 AM";
TimeSpan _time = TimeSpan.Parse(timeValue.Replace(" AM", "").Replace(" PM", ""));
```

Or you could use the DateTime.Parse and use the TimeOfDay property.

```
string timeValue = "08:55 AM";
TimeSpan _time = DateTime.Parse(timeValue).TimeOfDay;
if (_time > TimeSpan.FromHours(12)) _time -= TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
```

I prefer the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert that kind of strings to a TimeSpan with this code

```
TimeSpan _time;
string input = "08:55 PM";
string[] fmts = new string[] {@"hh\:mm\ \A\M", @"hh\:mm\ \P\M"};
if(TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, fmts, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _time))
{
    if(input.EndsWith("PM"))
       _time = _time.Add(new TimeSpan(12,0,0));
    Console.WriteLine(_time.ToString());        
}
```

Comment: While that does work, I think it's better to understand _why_ it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Yes I agree with that. The problem seems to have something that is not clearly explained. It would be better if it is possible to use a DateTime instead of a TimeSpan